# std::map : update key when using custom operator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, stdmap

When using a custom operator for `std::map<KeyType,ValueType,Comparator>`, which by design only compares some of my KeyType's fields, it is possible that two objects `KeyType k1, k2` contain different data but for the map they look like the same key. After all, this is the reason why we wrote our custom Comparator in the first place.

So if I write

```
map[k1] = 1;
map[k2] = 2;
```

with k1 and k2 such that the comparator reports them as being equal, the map will contain the key/value pair `{k1, 2}`.

What is the most elegant way to replace the pair `{k1, 1}` by `{k2, 2}` or is the only way to erase k1 first and then insert k2?

Comment: If `k1` is equal to `k2`, `{k1, 2}` should equal to `{k2, 2}`. If they are not, your comparator is broken (or not sufficient for this case). (Are you sure you want a `std::map` and select the right key-type/comparator ?)

Comment: I don't think there is a better wey to replace the pair other than what you imagine. As alternative have you think of to have as value the  pair key+value?

Comment: @appleapple Yes, the map should behave this way to automatically filter for "uniqueness" of certain KeyType-members (not all). So my equality definition is based only on some of them. Example: The KeyType has the member ``jobDescription`` and I only want one teacher, one programmer, one janitor... in my map (but they have other members that might differ, e.g. ``surname``). If I add a second teacher to the map, the old one should be overwritten, i.e. the key updated with the new person data. Concerning the comparator, nothing changed - but the surname did change

Comment: @PhilLab isn't it should be `map[job_type::teacher]=new_teacher`?

Comment: @appleapple not in this map, because the value type is something different. I just happen to need the additional "filtering" and was thinking about whether this could be achieved with a simple map

Answer (score 1):

I can find two distinct ways of replacing a key from a map with an *equivalent* key:

#### The quick-and-dirty method

Just `swap` a key with another, it *is* UB, but it should be fine with most of `std::map` implementations:

```
std::swap(const_cast<Key&>(map.find(k2)->first), k2);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/229477cfa500dd17).

#### The less-quick-and-less-dirty method

Provide an adjustment `const` method `Key` which change it's internal state:

```
void adjust(const Key& other) const { value = other.value; }
```

An improvement being to check that this method transforms a `Key` to an equivalent `Key`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1469f63e395c235c) (improvements let to OP).

Comment: Thanks for the Demos! UB is difficult to justify, so I wouldn't use it